# Do special Facebook permissions need to be reviewed if they are requested after login?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm asking for standard permissions when the user logs in. I don't ask for special permissions in the login because I don't know whether they will actually use my special features.

```
[FBSession
    openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"]
    allowLoginUI:YES
    completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
        // stuff
    }
 ];
```

After the user is logged in and wanders around my app a little, they may tap a share button that posts something to their wall. At this point I will ask for an additional *publish_actions* permission:

```
[[FBSession activeSession]
    requestNewPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
    defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone
    completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
        // if acquired, post to their wall
    }
];
```

Does my app still require [Login Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login) if I request my users for *publish_actions* at some time after they've already logged in? What I'm trying to ask is: does Login Review only apply to the exact moment of logging in, as its name implies? I'm just a skeptical of the naming of "Login Review" - it seems too good to be true.

Comment: It applies to every time you ask for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an empirical test, requesting for `publish_actions` shows a warning message from Facebook saying that the action must be approved by April 30, 2015. This means that "Login Review" is a misnomer because it applies to non-login related permissions as well.